# WKWebView does not actually follow redirects

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit, wkwebview, http-redirect

I have a simple `WKWebView` in macOS. I'm facing issues with redirection when visiting a page without www that then redirects to the subdomain www.

As far as I could find out I'd simply have to allow the navigation request and the webView should handle everything itself. But the redirect never actually happens. The webView ends up in a redirect loop, calling `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:` over and over again until finally failing with `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"`

Safari, other browsers and clients do indeed succeed, what makes me believe that it's not a server issue.
Also when I enter the address redirected to directly, it does work without any issues.

I implemented the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol as follows:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if ([navigationAction navigationType] == WKNavigationTypeOther) {
        if ([[[[navigationAction request] URL] host] isEqualToString:[[[self webView] URL] host]]) {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
            NSLog(@"allowed");
            return;
        }
    
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        NSLog(@"cancelled: %@", [navigationAction request]);
    }
    else {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didStartProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSLog(@"provisional navigation started");
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation; {
    NSLog(@"provisional navigation received redirect");
}
```

I'm expecting the webView to accept and actually follow the redirect after I answered using `WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow`.

When I execute a request the following happens:

1. decidePolicyForNavigationAction: for main domain name
2. I respond with allow
3. didStartProvisionalNavigation:
4. decidePolicyForNavigationAction: for redirect with subdomain
5. I respond with allow
6. didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:
7. Back to 6.

Do I have to somehow "commit" the redirect or do it manually myself?
Any ideas or did I miss something completely?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. Really. Embarrassingly stupid.
My table now has my face embossed.

My original code was cut down for overview until a point where I deleted my issue...

I'm working on a special use case where the host name is not in the URL. I connect to a multi-site web server via it's IP and set the Host header accordingly to get the desired page.

When redirected I copy the request, set the header accordingly and resend the request. Guess what? Responding to a redirect by sending the same `Host:`  header will result in another redirect. Grr.

I'll leave this here for public amusement to a day or two